# Is there a way to capture crash data on Windows?

Tags: system

I have a very large notebook which I've been working on for years.  Every day, after I add to it, I save it as PDF.  Recently Mathematica has crashed when I try to save it as PDF.  Mathematica just disappears.  No message from it, nor from Windows.

Is there a way to capture data about the Mathematica process, such as a log?

Comment: They always ask for data to reproduce the crash or an error as opposed to including 'log files' so it is probably possible internally, which makes it a question for WRI.

Comment: It is a bad idea to have a large notebook...even worse to have a very large notebook. This is from my personal experience.

Comment: The happy news is that I fixed the problem.  Working on a copy of the problematic notebook, I intended to perform "block troubleshooting" as we electronics techs called it in the Army.  Divide the circuit in half and figure out which half holds the fault.  Repeat until you find the wrong sized bolt in the patch panel shorting the circuit to a high resistance ground.  While holding the shift key and scrolling to select content, Mathematica hung up when I reached a certain cell.  I deleted that cell (one of my favorite graphics), and voilà!  Reentered the graphics code by hand, and all's good.

Comment: The self-test error Mathematica coughed up was LineWrapBox-c-4627.  I reported it, but heard nothing back, as yet.